# cannot access protected member declared in class from a friend function in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

i've a base class as follows:

//base class- arrayListType.h

```
class arrayListType
{
public:
//some function members;

protected:
elemType *list;
int length;
int maxSize;
};
```

and then a derived class:

//derived class- polynomialType.h

```
#include "arrayListType.h"

class polynomialType: public arrayListType<double>
{
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ,const polynomialType&);
friend istream& operator>>(istream& ,polynomialType&);

public:
polynomialType operator+(const polynomialType&);
polynomialType operator-(const polynomialType&);
//polynomialType operator*(const polynomialType&);
double operator() (double x);
polynomialType(int size = 100);
int min(int x,int y) const;
int max(int x,int y) const;
};
```

But after compiling the code, i got error as;

```
error C2248: 'arrayListType<elemType>::length' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'arrayListType<elemType>'
```

i've searched for solutions, but can't find ,please help.
definition of operator>> is given for refference;

```
istream& operator>>(istream is,polynomialType& p)
{
cout << "the degree of this polynomial is" << p.length-1 << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
{
    cout << "enter coefficient of x^" << i <<": ";
    is >> p.list[i];
}
return is;
}
```

the error shows only for friend functions only, why is it so??

Comment: Have you tried putting the `friend` functions under your `public:` definition?

Comment: `friend` declarations do not need to be under any specific access modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& ,polynomialType&);
```

verses

```
istream& operator>>(istream is,polynomialType& p)
```

Your stream function forgot the reference operator `&` and therefore has a different function signature. Not only that but it can also lead to subtle bugs such as *copying* the stream object (which may or may not have additional side effects) instead of re-using it.

Comment: Streams are not copyable; the only thing that could happen here would be moving a stream in (which is hard not to notice).

Comment: Indeed, STL streams are not copyable; non-standard streams may be copyable. Without `::std::` fully-qualified identifier, namespace issues may cause `istream` to resolve to a custom type of the same name.